# Shared Preferences Flutter 'get Int' was called on null Flutter

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I want to save data via shared preferences, but it does not work.
Can anyone help me? I get this error:

After I press on the button this error appears. I guess that the problem is either the Button or the update method which is called when the Button get presseed.

The set and get int method in the update method didn't ot work. I hope i could help you with this text.

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The method 'getInt' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: getInt("userLevel")
```

**HERE IS MY CODE**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Satz extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SatzState createState() => _SatzState();
}

class _SatzState extends State<Satz> {
  static const String USERLEVEL ='userLevel';
  int userLevel = 1;
  SharedPreferences prefs;
  int commacount= 2;
  int i =0;
  String stringValue = '';
  Map<int, String> getsatz ={
    1 : 'Ich finde diese App gut da ich hierdurch die Kommasetzung lerne. ',
    2 : 'Paul wo bist du ?',
    3: 'Wenn das Wetter morgen gut wird können wir uns gerne bei mir treffen',
    4: 'Der Baum der dort steht ist schon über 40 Jahre alt.',
  };
  Map<int,String> rightSatz = {
    1 : 'Ich finde diese App gut, da ich hierdurch die Kommasetzung lerne. ',
    2 : 'Paul, wo bist du ?',
    3: 'Wenn das Wetter morgen gut wird, können wir uns gerne bei mir treffen',
    4: 'Der Baum, der dort steht, ist schon über 40 Jahre alt.',
  };
  Map<int, int> getcommacount ={
    1: 1,
    2:1,
    3:1,
    4:2,
  };  @override
  void initState(){
    readUserLevel();
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('refresh');
    return Scaffold(backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Satz '+userLevel.toString(),
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontSize: 30,
        ),),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [ 
                          Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 20, 10, 10),
                            child: Card(
                                color: Colors.yellow,
                                child:
                   
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                child: RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  children:  newmethod()
                )
                ),
            )

            ),
                            ),
                         RaisedButton(
            shape:RoundedRectangleBorder(
              side: BorderSide(color:Colors.black, width:2.0),
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 10, 50, 10),
            onPressed: (){
              if (stringValue == rightSatz[userLevel]) {
                if (userLevel >= 4) {
                  setState(() {
                                   updateUserLevel.call(USERLEVEL,1);
                                   //readLevels();
                                   stringValue='';
                  });
                } else {
                  updateUserLevel(USERLEVEL,1);
                  setState(() {
                  updateUserLevel.call(USERLEVEL,1); 
                  //readUserLevel();
                  stringValue ='';
                  });
                }
              } else {print('wrong value');
              }
             // Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Satz()));
            },
            color: Colors.yellow
            ,child:
            Text('Prüfen',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),),
          ) 
                        ],
                      ),
                  
          ),
          
    );
  }
 newmethod(){

    if (stringValue =='') {

         stringValue = getsatz[userLevel];
    commacount = getcommacount[userLevel];
    print(userLevel);
    }
    return 
    stringValue.split(' ').asMap().entries.map((entry) {
      print('worked as well');
                    String text = entry.value;
                    int index = entry.key;
                    return TextSpan(
                            text: text + " ",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 50),
                            recognizer: new TapGestureRecognizer()
                                ..onTap = () {
                                  if (commacount == 1) {
                                  List<String> correctedValue = stringValue.replaceAll(',','').split(' ');
                                  print(correctedValue[index]);
                                  if(!text.contains(',')){
                                    correctedValue[index] += ',';                      
                                  }
                                  setState(
                                    () {
                                      stringValue = correctedValue.join(' ');
                                    },
                                  );}
                                  if (commacount ==2) {
                                    if (i != commacount) {
                                      List<String> correctedValue stringValue.replaceAll(',',',').split(' ');
                                    
                                  print(correctedValue[index]);
                                  if(!text.contains(',')){
                                    correctedValue[index] += ',';                      
                                  }
                                  setState(
                                    () {
                                      stringValue = correctedValue.join(' ');
                                      i++;
                                    },
                                  );
                                  
                                  }else{
                                    List<String> correctedValue = stringValue.replaceAll(',','').split(' ');
                                    setState(() {
                                      i =0;
                                    });
                                    
                                  print(correctedValue[index]);
                                  if(!text.contains(',')){
                                    correctedValue[index] += ',';                      
                                  }
                                  setState(
                                    () {
                                      stringValue = correctedValue.join(' ');
                                    },
                                  );}
                                  }
                                },
                    );
                  }).toList();
  
  }
   readUserLevel()async{
      prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      int userLevel = prefs.getInt(USERLEVEL);
      if (userLevel== null) {
        await prefs.setInt(USERLEVEL, 1);
      }
      setState(() {
        userLevel = userLevel;
      });
    }
    
     void updateUserLevel(String key, int value){
      switch(key){
        case USERLEVEL:{
          int userLevel = prefs.getInt(key);
            userLevel += value; 
          print(userLevel);
          prefs.setInt(key, value);

        }
        break;
      }
    }
}
```

I already tried severeal ways to solve this problem. I would be very thankful If anyone could answer my Question.

Comment: Remove async/await since SharedPreferences.getInstance() does not return a Future, also use setState to update the prefs.setInt

Comment: where do I have specifical add the setState? I get now the error getInt was called on null

Comment: if(userLevel!= null) {
        setState(() { userLevel = userLevel; });
      }

Comment: May I'm to dumb, but it doesn't work. Do could insert the code part in the whole code. I would be very happy :)